# Handling field separator option

Tags: bash

Have been constructing an array that can be used to populate options to find. `${incl[@]}` made from function parameter arguments that takes filename suffixes.

```
# get parameter arguments
("--incl")
  incl+=("$2") ; shift 2 ;;  # file type suffix
```

Example using `--incl .texi --incl .org` gives `incl=( .texi .org )`.

But I also have the option for the user to pass a delimiter called `fs`, so one can use `--incl .texi,.org` by using `--fs ","`. This means that if `fs` is specified, I would need to split each element of array incl.

But I believe there is repetition in the code and possible fails in some circumstances. It could need some cleaning up, and need suggestions and analysis.

```
  if [[ -z "$fs" ]]; then  # undefined field separator

    isufx=( '(' )
    for ext in "${incl[@]}"; do
      isufx+=( -name "*$ext" -o )    # for find cmd
    done
    isufx[${#isufx[@]}-1]=')'  # modify last -o with )
  
  else

    isufx=( '(' )

    for ext in "${incl[@]}"; do

      if [[ "$ext" == *"$fs"* ]]; then
        s=${ext//"$fs"/" "}
        for fltyp in $s; do
          isufx+=( -name "*$fltyp" -o )  # for find cmd
        done
      else
        isufx+=( -name "*$ext" -o )  # for find cmd
      fi

    done

    isufx[${#isufx[@]}-1]=')'  # modify last -o with )

  fi
```

Comment: Is this a good way for an if condition `[[ -z "$fs" && "$ext" == *"$fs"* ]]`.  If I remember, one can also introduce parentheses. So it becomes `[[ (-z "$fs") && ("$ext" == *"$fs"*) ]]`.

Answer (score 1):

The code the variable `s` that splits according to the value of `fs`.
A more compact implementation is to use the variable `s`, then decide whether to split tho value of `s`, or not.

Thus, the following code

```
  isufx=( '(' )

  for ext in "${incl[@]}"; do

    s="$ext"
    [[ ! -z "$fs" && "$ext" == *"$fs"* ]] && s=${ext//"$fs"/" "}
    for fltyp in $s; do
      isufx+=( -name "*$fltyp" -o )   # options for find cmd
    done

  done

  isufx[${#isufx[@]}-1]=')'  # modify last -o with )

  if (( vb >= 2 )); then
    echo "isufx[*]: ${isufx[*]}"  
  fi
```